# NLog strange behavior on production server

Tags: json, nlog, iis-8

Something strange happens to me with NLog once published on run server.

I configure it like this :

```
        "targets": {
        "all-file": {
            "type": "File",
            "fileName": "${var_logdir}/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log",
            "layout": {
                "type": "JsonLayout",
                "Attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "timestamp",
                        "layout": "${longdate}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "level",
                        "layout": "${level}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "logger",
                        "layout": "${logger}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "message",
                        "layout": "${message:raw=true}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "properties",
                        "encode": false,
                        "layout": {
                            "type": "JsonLayout",
                            "includeallproperties": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "username",
                        "layout": "${aspnet-user-identity}"
                    }

                ]
            }
```

and rules like that :

```
            {
            "logger": "*",
            "minLevel": "Trace",
            "writeTo": "all-file"
        },
```

It works flawlessly in dev environment, I'm able to log since trace up to fatal but when I go to prod, I'm only able to log from warning level.

I compared my appsetings.json in prod, and it is exactly the same than debug.

Any idea?

Comment: What's the content of appsettings.json? Is there a appsettings.prod.json?

Comment: Hi, no ther is no appsettingd.prod.json, only the one define in development

Comment: Have you checked whether application pool identity have full permission to read/write ${var_logdir}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for pointing me out the appsettings.json content. I was stuck on NLog configuration thinking the problem was here, but in fact no, it was here :

```
    "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
    }
},
```

The default was Warning, so, dfficult to log levels below. I changed to Debug, and it works fine.